# Cannot create AKS with Windows OS in AKS-Preview

Tags: azure, preview, azure-aks

I faced below error when I tried to create AKS with Windows OS following steps in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli)

```
az aks create \
    --resource-group DockerResourceGroup \
    --name win-test-aks \
    --node-count 2 \
    --enable-addons monitoring \
    --kubernetes-version 1.14.6 \
    --generate-ssh-keys \
    --windows-admin-password "P@ssw0rd12345" \
    --windows-admin-username testuser \
    --enable-vmss \
    --network-plugin azure
```

> Error:
>   Operation failed with status: 'Bad Request'. Details: Virtual Machine Scale Set agent nodes are not allowed since feature "Microsoft.ContainerService/WindowsPreview" is not enabled. Please see https://aka.ms/aks/previews for how to enable features.

I tried to run `az feature list -o table` with below features installed already:

```
Microsoft.ContainerService/MultiAgentpoolPreview   Registered
Microsoft.ContainerService/VMSSPreview             Registered
Microsoft.ContainerService/WindowsPreview          Registered
Microsoft.Web/CentralUSRegionEnabled               Registered
```

Comment: seems you have not enabled Microsoft.ContainerService/WindowsPreview

Comment: Do you install the latest Azure CLI extension aks-preview?

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan, it shows that WindowsPreview is registered (shown as above).

Comment: What about the problem? Do you solve it?

Comment: Hi @CharlesXu, I was using latest aks-preview already. faced error *No updates available for 'aks-preview'. Use --debug for more information.* after running `az extension update --name aks-preview`

Comment: On my side, there is no problem with the command through the test, so the command is actually right. I doubt your subscription does not actually register the Microsoft.ContainerService/WindowsPreview. Try to register again.

Answer (score 1):

Did you refresh your registration of the AKS resource provider?

```
az provider register -n Microsoft.ContainerService
```